# No text for <br> in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scraper

Why does this not work, when there is `<br>` in the text? I get an empty text.

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
address = 'http://www.bbc.com'
response = opener.open(address)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
snaptext = soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'displaytext'})
print snaptext.string
```

An example, would be:

```
< p > blahblahblah< br/ >blah2blah2blah2< br/ >< p >
```

If there's a `< br >` in the text, the result is None

Answer (score -2):

As you can see here, br is not the issue, it's your use of .string, it will always return `None`, because it doesn't have attribute `.string`. You probably want to use `.getText()`

```
>>> x = bs.find('div', attrs={'id': 'forum-post-body-183'})
>>> x
<div class="j-comment-body forum-post-body u-typography-format text" id="forum-post-body-183" itemprop="text">
<p>Let's try it! I will only replace Sir Finley with Ysera for late game pressing (and ev. win condition).<br>In edit of this comment i would report about results in casual battles (for start).</br></p>
</div>
>>> x.string
>>> print(x.string)
None
>>> x.getText()
"\nLet's try it! I will only replace Sir Finley with Ysera for late game pressing (and ev. win condition).In edit of this comment i would report about results in casual battles (for start).\n"
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks.